# numpy interation in python without FOR loop

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops

i have a following numpy array.
`array([11, 11, 51, 11, 11, 51, 51, 11, 11, 51])` which has a shape `(10,)`

I want to make it to `array([[11], [11], [51], [11], [11], [51], [51], [11], [11], [51]])` and shape should be `(10,1)`.

One way to do it using the for loop, but i think which is not good way to get this done.

can someone suggest a more proper way?

thanks

Comment: I would really like to see the `for loop` solution.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny it is like this-: 1. i corvert into list. then make list of lists. and then convert it to numpy array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = np.array([11, 11, 51, 11, 11, 51, 51, 11, 11, 51])
a = a.reshape(-1,1)
```

`(-1,1)` means that you want the second shape to be exactly `1` and the first shape will be inferred from the length of the array.